# Change div content dynamically on ng-click AngularJS

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to display some data and tables in the content `div` which depends on which category you choose on the left hand side navigation.
So if I change the category also the displayed content of the content div should change.

Here is my code on [Plunkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/knaGTyenFzUnggQ3UYWG).

But it seems that not even this simple example is working.

So I have two Questions:

1.) How can I fix this example code to run ?

But more important:

2.) **Is there a better way to change the content div when you change the category ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I removed 'this' elements from code and also changed ng-view to ng-show.

```
<div>
  <div ng-show="showApple">{{content}}</div>
  <div ng-show="showBanana">{{content}}</div>
  <div ng-show="showOrange">{{content}}</div>
</div>
```

There was something wrong with that you named your div class "content" so I removed that also.

I am sure it isn't a perfect solution but now it works.

[link to plnkr](https://plnkr.co/edit/wCa7es8B4VOkCkPGjJrR?p)

Comment: It works and thanks for sharing but I can't help but think there's a fair bit of code just to do something really simple. JQuery tabs does all that with just this: `$( "#tabs" ).tabs();`

Answer (score 2):

To be honest your best bet is to use $states/views. With a data-ui-view on the content div and a data-ui-sref link on the button on your menu, you can easily switch out content. Take a look at the [ui-router](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Multiple-Named-Views) page to get a better understanding of it. With templates for each 'view' that your menu will click to, your code will not just be much easier to manage, but probably more understandable.

Comment: but is it possible to use a ng-view directive inside another ng-view ? becase the page my content is shown is just a template loaded inside the ng-view

Comment: Yes you can, see this [nested states/views](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Nested-States-&-Nested-Views) link

Answer (score 2):

You can use ng-include to show your contents but you have to keep them in seperate files e.g contentForApple, contentForBanana and contentForOrange.
Here I can show you a little change in your div

```
  <div class="content">
    <div ng-show="MainCtrl.showApple" ng-include ="'contentForApple.html'"></div>
    <div ng-show="MainCtrl.showBanana" ng-include = "'contentForBanana.html'"></div>
    <div ng-show="MainCtrl.showOrange" ng-include = "'contentForOrange.html'"></div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help you. Take one json array for category and data and get details of json data which index is clicked

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>


<body ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="MyController">

    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3">
                <ANY ng-repeat="x in category" ng-click="getData($index)">
                {{x.category}}<br>
                </ANY>
            </div>

            <div class="col-lg-6">
                {{data}}
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>

<script>
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('MyController', function ($scope) 
{       
    $scope.data = '';
    $scope.category = [{category:'Apple',data:'Apple Data'},{category:'Banana',data:'Banana Data'},{category:'Orange',data:'Orange Data'}];

    $scope.getData = function(index)
    {
        $scope.data = $scope.category[index]['data'];
    }
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**I did  it with simple ngif**

1) Keep an Index of Page which needs to be is loaded now

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
   $scope.pageIndex = 0;

  /*
   * Updates current Page index
   */
  $scope.changeIndex= function(indexToChange){

       $scope.pageIndex = indexToChange;

    }
});
```

2) Load content based on selected index

```
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

    <div class="mainframe">
        <div class="navigation">
            <ul class="list-group">
              <li class="list-group-item" ng-click="changeIndex(0)">Home<span class="status-icon"></span></li>
                <li class="list-group-item" ng-click="changeIndex(1)">Sign Up<span class="status-icon"></span></li>
                <li class="list-group-item" ng-click="changeIndex(2)">About<span class="status-icon"></span></li>
            </ul>
        </div>


        <div class="content">
       <div ng-if="pageIndex == 0" ng-include ="'Home.html'"></div>
       <div ng-if="pageIndex == 1" ng-include = "'SignUp.html'"></div>
       <div ng-if="pageIndex == 2" ng-include = "'About.html'"></div>
      </div>
  </div>
```

**Final Result:

https://embed.plnkr.co/ic0eY2vwiOnChN2ahrEt/**