# Angular JS : How i can change content of asp.net page on click button

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-4

I have this page.chtml. How can I change the content with another HTML content when I click on the button "changecontent" in AngularJS using ng-click and ng-if? I call this page much time I want when I click on one I change content of one  but not all the page: have you an idea, please

```
$scope.changeContent = function(){

    }
```

partial view :

```
<div class="container">   

                        <div class="SvgPicto col-lg-1  col-md-1  col-sm-1  col-xs-1">
                            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Resources/Common/pic_famille.svg")" />
                        </div>
                        <div class="SvgPicto col-lg-1  col-md-1  col-sm-1  col-xs-1">
                            <img src="@Url.Content("~/Resources/Common/pic_GPL_car.svg")" />
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div class="row">
                       <div class="col-lg-4  col-md-4  col-sm-4  col-xs-4 ">
                           <button ng-click="changeContent()">Supprimer</button>
                       </div>
                     </div>
                 </div>
```

call view :

```
    <div class="container">
    <div class="row ">
        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-6">
            <div class="row">
                @Html.Partial("~/Views/Common/ConfigurationTemplate.cshtml", new ViewDataDictionary { { "isLeft", true } })
            </div>
            <hr />
```

Comment: Not sure I fully understood your question. But will that answer help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35475633/change-div-content-dynamically-on-ng-click-angularjs#answer-35476702

Comment: i use a partial view 4 time in my page.chtml and i want when i click on button in my partial vue i change all the content by another content thank an advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If you want to make changes dynamically, I would suggest to make the following:

```
<div class="row" ng-show="contentToggle">
     @Html.Partial("~/Views/Common/ConfigurationTemplate.cshtml", new ViewDataDictionary { { "isLeft", true } })
</div>
<div class="row" ng-show="!contentToggle">
     @Html.Partial("~/Views/Common/ConfigurationTemplate2.cshtml", new ViewDataDictionary { { "isLeft", true } })
</div>
<input type="button" value="Toggle Content" ng-click="toggleContent()/>
```

And in Angular controller you would do:

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.contentToggle = true;

  $scope.toggleContent = function() {
    $scope.contentToggle = !$scopeContentToggle;
  }
});
```

Where ConfigurationTemplate is your first view and ConfigurationTemplate2 is a second content you want to display on click. And that you will need for four your Partial Views.

Comment: @sani was it any helpful?

Comment: yes the button is in the partial view and i need when i click in the button i change the content with another content for exemple i change all content by  an <text< or <button> ...

Comment: have you an idea please

Comment: if answer helped you please mark it correct. Put the button that is in my example into Partial view. I don't understand your request. Could you just provide more code to see your problem?

Comment: I use the same partial view 4 times in the same page chtml and I want to be clicked on a button in the partial view I change the continuation of this partial view by another continues and i want to know how i can do that please

Comment: Why putting this button in your partial view doesn’t help?

Comment: because it's a fonctionnalitie of my project  andrii :) and i need to put the button in my partial view

Comment: put that button in your partial view:) will it work that way?

Comment: I can invite you to chat, and discuss issue there

Comment: i have 10 reputation i dont succed to tchat :(

Comment: oh, right, that reputation thingy:) You put button to your partial view. Can you do that? will your Angular controller be a context for that partial view or that's different controller? if same controller, than your `ng-click` should still bind correctly to your controller. you might also want to put `ng-show="contentToggle"` and `ng-show="!contentToggle"` to different html tags I suppose.

Comment: yes the button is in the partial vue and i use the same controller

Comment: no he doesn't work i want to change the content with another contentwhen i clik in the partial vuebutton

Comment: look: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSwitch ; see example, content changes, but they are usign select instead of button. I don't know how I can help you more. I don't see your code, I gave you examples how to change one visible content to another.

Comment: thanks andrri i will give you more code tomorow thank an advance

Comment: sure, no problem:)

Comment: have you a profil linked in andrii? please  i want to keep contact with you :)

Comment: Hello Andrii are you here

Comment: Hi @sani, I am here now

Comment: how are you andrii

Comment: good, thanks. how are you? Still working on that problem? Let me see what you have.

Comment: sure, go ahead.

Comment: i invited you  :)

Comment: you recieveed my invitation

Comment: ahave you recieved andrri?

Comment: i added question :)